How to add a point to a leaderboard whenever a tool is used via Lua?
I've written some code that allows a player to take a sip of the item "OrangeJuiceTool" in the StarterPack, and whenever a sip is taken, the Sips value in the script update and add one, however whenever a sip is taken, no values are added. Here is my code:
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local DataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("TimeStats")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    local Leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    Leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    Leaderstats.Parent = Player

    local Sips = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Sips.Name = "Sips"
    Sips.Value = 0
    Sips.Parent = Leaderstats

    local tool = game.StarterPack:WaitForChild("OrangeJuiceTool")

    local Data = DataStore:GetAsync(Player.UserId)
    if Data then
        Sips.Value = Data
    end

    local function IncrementSips()
        Sips.Value = Sips.Value + 1
    end

    tool.Equipped:Connect(IncrementSips)

    Player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(Character)
        local Tool = Character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Tool")
        if Tool and Tool.Name == "OrangeJuiceTool" then
            Tool.Activated:Connect(IncrementSips)
        end
    end)
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(Player)
    DataStore:SetAsync(Player.UserId, Player.leaderstats.Sips.Value)
end)


I tried to update the code with different functions, didn't work :(

The first tool.Equipped:Connect(IncrementSips) is unnecessary, because that tool will never be equipped by anyone. Only clones of that tool will.

have you tried using remote events?
make a remote event in replicated storage
then make a local script in the tool
local remote = game.ReplicatedStorage.yourRemoteEvent
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local tool = game.StarterPack:WaitForChild("OrangeJuiceTool")

tool.Equipped:Connect(function(plr)
    remote:FireServer(plr) -- firing remote
end)

and then make a script in server script service
local remote = game.ReplicatedStorage.yourRemoteEvent
remote.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
    plr.leaderstats.Sips.Value += 1
end)


hey there, just tried what you suggested and still the same issue.

Your remote event isn't secured. I would recommend a check if the player has the tool and a debounce or an attacker might spam the leaderboard even without having the tool.

I am not sure if this is the case but I think the tool might not have been loaded in yet, you could do this to fix it if that's the case
 Player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(Character)
        local Tool -- Creating a variable but not setting its value yet
        if Character:WaitForChild("OrangeJuiceTool"):IsA("Tool") then -- waiting for the child "OrangeJuiceTool" and also checking if that's a tool
                Tool = Character:WaitForChild("OrangeJuiceTool") -- if that's the tool, set the variable to it
                Tool.Activated:Connect(IncrementSips) -- finally connecting the function when the tool is activated
                
    end
end)

Note that this is only one part of the code, make changes so that it matches your own code
